# RxSwift, Divide Observable<[array]> into Observable<a>, Observable<b>

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a question abou RxSwift.

I have Observable<[Array]> and I need to separate it with Observable

How could I divide the observable Observable<[Array]> into observable ... N and do flatMap for each observable ?

Comment: So you want to convert from `Observable<[T]>` to `[Observable<T>]`? That doesn't even really make sense... Maybe you can me more clear in what you are asking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also a `.flatMap()` -

```
let array: Observable<[Array]> = ...
let items: Observable<ItemType> = array.flatMap { Observable.from($0) }.flatMap { /* */ }
```